# Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

When using TypeScript in conjunction with Jest, my specs would fail with error messages like:

```
test/unit/some.spec.ts:1:1 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.
test/unit/some.spec.ts:2:3 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.
test/unit/some.spec.ts:3:7 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
test/unit/some.spec.ts:7:1 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'test'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.
```

The types are already installed.

I use:

```
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.12",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "ts-jest": "^23.10.5",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
```

I run tests using `jest --forceExit --coverage --verbose`

Comment: Rename your folder from `test` to `tests`. Works for me!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After fiddling with the `tsconfig.json` for a while I finally figured that commenting the `"types": [],` will work.

#### Failing configuration (before)

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": []
  }
}
```

#### Working configuration

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // "types": []
  }
}
```

Comment: Or add jest to types: `"types": ["jest"]`

Comment: @Madeo did you add the `@types/jest` to the dev dependencies in your package.json?

Comment: Yes, I have added that, plus I have imported them into my test file. I have played with `excludes` and `types`, but nothing. Everything runs nicely, just that complaint from the compiler =(

Comment: Works in 2019 November

Answer (score 182):

It's a bit tricky one because both: your IDE (i.e., Visual Studio Code) and TypeScript use *tsconfig.json* for their own purposes.

#### Simple checklist to solve the initial problem:

(for TypeScript and Jest)

1. Make sure you have `@types/jest` and `@types/node` installed.
2. Make sure you have linked these types in `tsconfig.json` so that: `"types": ["jest", "node"]`
3. Make sure you **don't have your tests or the tests directory excluded** from `tsconfig.json` configuration in `excluded` property.

#### Side effect on transpilation

If you transpile from TypeScript to JavaScript using `tsc` or any custom module that relies on `tsconfig.json` then you may notice that your tests will be transpiled too in such case (you'll see their .js correspondence in your build directory).

However, in most cases you will have either:

1. separate `tsconfig.prod.json` with a configuration that overwrites the default one. There are many settings like `inlineSource`, `sourceMaps`, `inlineSourceMaps` which you'd probably want to disable too and then use `tsc --project tsconfig.prod.json` to build
2. terminal (npm/yarn script) command that overwrites the default configuration with the specific flags. Example: `npx tsc --inlineSourceMap false --declarationMap false --inlineSources false --sourceMap false`. At that point you can use `--excludeFiles` or `--excludeDirectories` flag to exclude your tests from the build [as per documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

The alternative is to use package like [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) and delete unnecessary files as a part of the build process. It might be less complex than overwriting the configuration and easier to maintain as a build step. In such a case, you may use the command: `yarn rimraf build/**/*.test.js`.

##### IDE or TypeScript service restart

Note that sometimes it may take a moment for your IDE (or exactly TypeScript service) to pick up the changes. Give it a few seconds to sink in. At the right bottom frame of your IDE (VSCode or WebStorm) you can find an annotation e.g. *"TypeScript 4.2.1"*. Click on this and select: "Restart service" to be sure that the solution is working on not before you move on.

Comment: What I found is that if I remove , "**/*.spec.ts" from the "excluded" property in tsconfig.json, then the red underline in VS Code goes away for "describe" in .spec files, however those files are now output into /lib folder as part of the package. 

It seems like there is no way to exclude .spec files from the package, but include partially to get 'describe` errors to go away?

Comment: @Ross just amended my post

Comment: For me, I also needed to add the "test/" directory to the "include"-section of my `tsconfig.json` and then it worked. This answer gave me the idea that this might be something that needs to be done.

Comment: I think this is the most complete answer, However, it's very important to restart VSCode. In my case, I didn't restart which wasted me tons of time.

Comment: I guess the short answer would be add `"jest"` to `types` in `tsconfig.json` so it be come: `"types": ["jest", "node"]`.

Comment: Number 3 was very useful to me. Also #1: @types/jest for `jest`, `describe`, and `it`; @types/node for `global`. It also seems I could have removed `compilerOptions.types` or state them explicitly (thx @Mark).

Comment: @JianwuChen all the great solutions aside, after applying them, restart VSCode is the 'hidden' gotcha that really needs to be emphasized upon. Thank you.

Comment: @JianwuChen- thank you, I've emphasised this in the answer now.

Answer (score 161):

I'm using Visual Studio Code as my IDE and in my Angular project, and I had to comment-out/remove types in file *tsconfig.json* and add "jest" in types in *tsconfig.spec.json*.

#### File *tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // "types": []
  }
}
```

#### File *tsconfig.spec.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["jest", "node"]
  }
}
```

Comment: I also had to remove "typeRoots" from my tsconfig file, which was apparently overriding "types".

Comment: @Freekwalker -- deleting `typeRoots` fixed it for me

Comment: Note: you only need to add `"jest"` to `compilerOptions.types` if it's already defined in your tsconfig. If omitted entirely, the default behavior for that setting is to include all type under `node_modules/@jest`. I encountered this problem because my project was misconfigured with `types: []`, but after removing it entirely I got correctly typed Jest stuff.  By defining it the way it's shown in this solution, you're losing implicit inclusion of other types under `node_modules/@types` (which isn't bad, just a side effect to be aware of).

Comment: I helped a coworker with this issue; you *need* `types` under `compilerOptions`. FYI for others who have this problem and happen to miss this detail

Comment: [Official Docs for "typeRoots"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) and [Official Docs for "compilerOptions.types"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types) are worth a read.

Comment: @Freewalker your suggestion worked fine for me

Comment: FWIW, I'm using VSCode 1.74.2, not using Angular, and have no "types" or "typeRoots" settings.  Adding the `tsconfig.spec.json` file seems to have no effect, but if I modify the `tsconfig.json` itself to not exclude my tests directory, as described in the answer by Greg Wozniak, then I can make VSCode happy.

Answer (score 89):

This worked for me:

```
import '@types/jest';
```

Comment: Nice quick fix!

Comment: It gives me ``Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'jest' instead of '@types/jest'.`` when running tests.

Comment: It doesn't have an error but when trying to run the test: `Cannot find module '@types/jest' from 'pages/index.test.tsx'`

Comment: Can you add more information? E.g., what versions of the different parts? On what platform (Node.js version, npm version, hardware, and operating system, all including editions and versions).

Comment: note that you need to add once, probably only in jest.config.js

Answer (score 58):

None of the previous answers fixed my issue.

I had to add `"@types/jest"` to the `types` array in the *tsconfig.json* file.

Comment: Thanks, it works for my project which is using typescript and typescript-eslint

Comment: Thank you! btw, in my case it's a mono repo with multiple packages in it and this answer was the only one that fixed the problem. I added it on the root tsconfig.json

Comment: The only thing that worked for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 41):

The only way I was able to fix this was by adding the `tests/` folder to "include" in the *tsconfig.json* file:

```
"include": [
  "src/**/*.ts",
  "tests/*.ts"
]
```

For those who also have [ESLint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESLint) complaining, you need to add [Jest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jest_(JavaScript_framework)) to your `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
"env": {
  "es2020": true,
  "node": true,
  "jest": true
}
```

Comment: Thank you, adding to include was the only thing that helped here too!

Comment: Oops, this did work to resolve the error within VS Code, but then my package stopped working (include failing) in other contexts.  No idea why that happened, but I'm going to look for another solution.

Answer (score 23):

You have to import Jest in your test file:

```
import 'jest';
```

Another way to solve it is adding it in your *tsconfig.json* file:

```
   "compilerOptions": {
     "types": [ "node", "jest" ],
     "moduleResolution": "node"
   }
```

If you are using [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/), the problem may be a not necessary comma at the end of your *tsconfig.json* file, for example:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],  // Remove this comma
}
```

Comment: Yeah extra comma was my issue. Thank you

Comment: `import 'jest'` helps, I'm trying to use custom tsconfig.json location

Answer (score 20):

In my case (Visual Studio Code, [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/), [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) workspaces, [Jest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jest_(JavaScript_framework)) v26, @types/jest, `"types": ["node", "jest"]` present in `tsconfig.json`) **tests were running OK**, but the IDE was **underlining** all `describe`s and `it`s with red.

Nothing helped until I **reloaded** the Visual Studio Code window after trying quite long.

Comment: Yes, i closed and reopened VS Code completely, then it worked =) Thanks

Comment: Sometimes you can just open up the command palette and choose Restart Typescript Language Server, but of course when I go to look right now I'm not seeing it  Maybe the update I just did removed it  In my case I forgot to install the npm dependencies on this new project  `npm i` and also needed our `.npmrc`. 

Comment: What do you mean by reloading the Visual Studio Code window? Restarting the application? Reloading some window inside of it? Or something else?

Comment: Sometimes, even after closing and opening vscode, it still happens. What fixed it is closing the test file and then opening it again. This is very silly behavior in vs code.

Answer (score 19):

The below configuration works for me. I added `node_modules/@types` to `typeRoots`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...rest of my settings
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["jest", "node"]
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked for me, I've added node_modules/@types to the typeRoots and removed types field from tsconfig

Comment: I love you, thanks

Comment: An explanation would be in order. Why does it work? What is the idea/gist? What is the crucial part? What versions of the different parts were installed? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65665656/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 13):

You need to include your test path in file *tsconfig.json*.

Example: suppose you named your path to `tests/` and put it in root project directory, you need to specify in "include" parameter from *tsconfig* to look out for testes files:

1. Go to: `tsconfig.json`
2. Add:

   ```
   "include": [
       "tests/*.<file_test_extension>",
   ],
   ```

   `<file_test_extension>:` ts | js | etc.

Comment: but this will start copying test files to lib folder which will get deployed

Comment: *"testes files"* sounds weird. What is it? Maybe I don't want to know?

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 10):

You can have a separate `tsconfig.json` in the test folder `__tests__`:

```json
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "../build",
        "noEmit": true,
        "rootDir": "../",
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}
```

which extends the one in the root folder:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts", "__tests__"]
}
```

This way, your test files still get excluded from the public build, but still get to share all the common options.

If you are using `includes` instead of or in conjunction with `excludes`, make sure to use that in your extension as well, for example:

```
tsconfig.json

{
  "includes": ["src"],
  ...
}

tests/tsconfig.json

{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json"
  "includes": ["../"]
}
```

This won't change what gets included in your build folder, but it will allow Visual Studio Code to find your Jest types.

Comment: this is the correct way.. i excluded `"**/*.test.ts"` because, if i didnt excluded that, VSCode will complaint all `*.ts` should be under `rootDir`.. but if i excluded it, then the error `describe blah...` will arise..

Answer (score 9):

> You need to include in tsconfig.json your test path.

I solved the problem by having a `tsconfig.json` and a `tsconfig.build.json` in my project root. `tsconfig.json` contains all options including

```
"include": ["src/**/*", "test/**/*"],
```

`tsconfig.build.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Then in `package.json` (clean script optional):

```
"scripts": {
  "clean": "rm -rf dist",
  "build": "npm run clean && tsc --build tsconfig.build.json,
  ...
}
```

Comment: This was the fix for me. I had the tests excluded in my tsconfig.json file because I didn't want them compiling to the dist folder. I ended up creating a separate tsconfig.build.json with the exclude in there, but left it included in the tsconfig.json and now the warnings are gone, and the tests excluded from the build. Thanks!

Comment: This is a response to [Victor Jatobá's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139158/cannot-find-name-describe-do-you-need-to-install-type-definitions-for-a-test/59073068#59073068).

Comment: I think this is the most elegant way to solve the issue - just two sibling config files.


In my case (I don't have a `test/` folder) in `tsconfig.json` just: `"include": [ "src/**/*.ts"],`, in the `tsconfig.build.json` :  `"exclude": [ "**/*.test.ts" ]`

Answer (score 8):

Another thing that could be wrong is if you have opened Visual Studio Code in a parent directory above your project. This happened to me because we are using [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) solutions, and I had the entire solution open, not just the project.

Simply put, make sure Visual Studio Code is open to the root of your project.

Answer (score 7):

[Greg Woz's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139158/cannot-find-name-describe-do-you-need-to-install-type-definitions-for-a-test/61107618#61107618) is the most complete answer. For my case, for some reason, the initial *tsconfig.json* file contains `"exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]`, which is the root cause. After that I removed `"**/__tests__/*"`. And make sure it also includes: `"types": ["jest"]`. It works.

Also, it is important to **restart Visual Studio Code** after configuration changes. It wastes me hours of time trying all the different ways without restarting it.

Comment: oh my gah thank you for mentioning that YOU NEED TO RESTART VSCODE! That was my issue this whole time. I spent an hour trying to change my config to no avail, not knowing that a vscode restart was necessary.

Comment: thx man. :) .... f**** restart cost me make all steps from answer above :P

Answer (score 7):

Since at least Jest 25, it has been possible to [import the Jest globals directly](https://jestjs.io/docs/api).  This is usually used in conjunction with the [`injectGlobals: false`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#injectglobals-boolean) config option or with [`--injectGlobals=false`](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--injectglobals) from the CLI.

For example:

`import { describe, expect, it, test } from '@jest/globals';`

Comment: Can you [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73126240/edit)? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"* (But ****** ***without*** ****** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: this is the best answer if you want to exclude jest test from your build, it also helps when jest goes in to conflict with `cypress`

Answer (score 6):

#### For [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) [monolithic repository](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monorepo) users

I'm running a Lerna monolithic repository and here's what I had to do to fix it:

1. Ensure `"@types/jest"` is in the devDependencies of file *package.json* of both the root package as well as the individual package in the `packages/` directory, and you have run `lerna bootstrap` to install / link those packages in your `node_modules` directories
2. Ensure the `"types": ["node", "jest"]` piece is in your root tsconfig.json.
3. I added `import 'jest';` to the top of my individual *.test.ts files.

Comment: Im a lerna monorepo user and I approve this message

Comment: I'm a lerna monorepo user, and I absolutely refuse to add 'import jest' in my test files. Luckily, the first two steps seem to be all I needed.

Answer (score 6):

[The solution suggested by Freewalker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139158/cannot-find-name-describe-do-you-need-to-install-type-definitions-for-a-test/66918141#comment104551057_54623931) in comments can easily be missed.  Removing "typeRoots" from the tsconfig file, which was apparently overriding "types" - resolved the issue.

Comment: What is the name of "the tsconfig file"? Where is it located?

Comment: This has the correct point.  From tsconfig remove "typeRoots" but include "types": ["jest", "node"] has solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the problem was in one particular file. I hadn't found the issue itself, but it was cured by adding `import {} from 'jest'` to the file's imports.

No other way from the Jest issue tracker, Stack Overflow or what not did help. It was just some crazy bug fixed by some crazy workaround.

Yes, and I added the latest `jest`, `ts-jest` and `@types/jest` to file *package.json* of course.

Comment: If you're going to import something, then is better to import the "describe" and "it" functions or whatever you need from jest

Comment: I used mocha but had the same problem, VSCode was complaining about `describe` and the other types missing even with `.eslintrc` overriding env with mocha. Adding a file in my test dir only doing `import { describe, before, it } from 'mocha'` solved the error in VSCode.

Answer (score 4):

None of the previous solutions above helped me.

I was using:

- [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)) 11
- Jest
- Uninstalled anything related to [Jasmine-Karma](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/karma-jasmine/info)
- `.spec` files are in same folder as components (auto-gen from `ng g`)

Adding `exclude` to **tsconfig.app.json** (not *tsconfig.json*) to ignore all specification files when serving the app worked for me.

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
"exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
]
```

`ng s` and `npm test` now work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
import {} from 'jasmine';
```

Add the above line to the code.

Answer (score 3):

Besides other answers, for me, explicit imports helped. Other answers with types didn't help because they were already implemented

```
import { expect, describe, it, test } from '@jest/globals';
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:

This is happening in Visual Studio Code. You need to run `npm i --save-dev @types/jest`, and in your

**tsconfig.json**

you need to place

`"jest"` in the types under `"compilerOptions"`

like

`"types": ["gapi", "gapi.auth2", "jest"],`

and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple reasons:

1. If `@types/jest` is not installed, try installing it. In the *tsconfig.json* file, define the types, for example, `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types/", "./src/@types/", ".src/**/@types/"]`
2. [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) issue: try to open Visual Studio Code in the project directory rather than opening it in its parent directory.

Answer (score 2):

I found a similar issue was caused by a version number mismatch between `@types/jest` and `jest`

Comment: Yes, most of the answers leave out version information - they working may be purely coincidental.

Comment: Matching the version numbers and "types": ["node", "jest"] in tsconfig, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Mocha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mocha_(JavaScript_framework)), [Chai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#JavaScript) and `chai-http` for testing a [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) project. I was not using `types` in `compilerOptions` earlier, but adding the below setting in file *tsconfig.json* made it work for me:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...rest of my settings
    "types": ["mocha", "chai", "chai-http"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to install the `ts-jest` dependency in your project:

```
yarn add ts-jest -D
```

In your `jest.config.ts` file, you need to set the line containing `preset: undefined` to `preset: 'ts-jest'`

```
// A preset that is used as a base for Jest's configuration
preset: 'ts-jest',
```

Answer (score 1):

The packages might have not installed properly. Do check if the package does really exist inside the *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)* folder. Like to this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72724360/how-to-fix-cannot-find-describe-in-jest), the TypeScript thingy was throwing the error, because its **node_modules** directory was empty.

Comment: to add to your comment it could be if npm run with flag --production

Answer (score 1):

I was still having the issue with `mocha` even after installing the type definition files from `@types/mocha`.

Just ensure that if you have configured `typeRoots` in your `tsconfig.json`, then `node_modules/@types` is equally added.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
       ...
       "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed `ts-jest` with `npm i -D ts-jest` and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing `tsconfig.json`, and all I had to do was run `tsc --init` and Visual Studio Code did not complain about "describe" any more:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow JavaScript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,      /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue today, as I was putting together a [POC](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proof_of_concept#Noun). I am using Protractor and [Jasmine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasmine_(JavaScript_testing_framework)) (as opposed to [Jest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jest_(JavaScript_framework)) or [Mocha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mocha_(JavaScript_framework))). It turns out I had to actually create the tsonfig file via a TypeScript utility/package.

Then, adding "jasmine" and "node" to the **types** array in *tsconfig* worked fine.

Here is the link I came across: *[TypeScript Compiler Configuration](https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/tsconfig-json/)*

Comment: What is the *"tsonfig file"*? Do you mean *"tsconfig file"*? What is the actual name of it? *tsconfig.json*?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I created `babel.config.js`, and it caused a problem. Also, we added `**/*.js` to `.gitignore` for compile files; our team has different environments.

If we use `ts-jest`, we don't need `babel.config.js`.

Answer (score 0):

In the VS Code IDE, if red squiggly lines persist despite installing all the necessary dev dependencies, then run the **Developer Reload Window command**.

Use the shortcut:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> OR  <kbd>F1</kbd>
- Type **Reload** and select **Developer: Reload Window** option.

Answer (score -1):

These solve my problem by adding @types/jest to my tesconfig file:

[image]