# Jest - Cannot find name describe for jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

After a year and a half that I have finished a project, I'm about to start testing another project with Jest and there for I had installed the necessary packages on the development level:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "supertest": "^6.1.6"
  }
```

When I have start to right automated testing code, right away I'm getting Errors warning:

```
Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jest` or `npm i --save-dev @types/mocha`.ts(2582)
```

I have search for this matter and found this article [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139158/cannot-find-name-describe-do-you-need-to-install-type-definitions-for-a-test](https://Stackoverflow)

As suggested I've tried to do adjustments in the tsconfig.json, but unfortunately this didn't resolve my problem.
Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es6" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,

    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "types": [
      "jest"
    ] /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */,

    /* Interop Constraints */
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,

    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*, tests/*.js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

For the tsconfig, it is also complaining the following:

```
No inputs were found in config file tsconfig.ts.
Specified  "include" paths where `["src/**/*, tests/*.js"]` and 'exclude' paths where '["node_modules"]'
```

How can I resolve these weird issues noticing that I'm not using typescript in my project and I'm not familiar with typescript at this moment.

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

After taking a break from this problem and do some research, I have manage to come up with a solution.
The solution is to install the package @jest/globals

With that installed I have import it to my test file.
Here is an example below:

```
const jest = require("@jest/globals");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../express-app");

let server;

jest.describe("Testing Auth Service", () => {
  jest.describe("/api/v1/", () => {
    jest.beforeEach(() => {
      server = require("../index");
    });
    jest.afterAll(async () => {
      await server.close();
    });
  });
});
```

If there is a better approach for this, please leave a comment.
I would appreciate it.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I solved it by just adding "jest" in the types of the tsconfig.spec.json

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "types": [
      "vitest/globals",
      "vitest/importMeta",
      "vite/client",
      "node",
      "jest" //added
    ],
    "jsx": "react"
  },
```